# Redirect home page to subdirectory with nginx

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, nginx

I want to have the WordPress installation in `/wordpress` in my root directory, but all the actual links be in the form of `domain.com/blog/something/` (site address).

By following a [tutorial](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory), I managed to put WordPress in its own directory, and change the site's address to `domain.com/blog` instead of just `domain.com`. All of the links work fine, except that I can still visit `domain.com` and see my page.

I would like to have `domain.com` redirect to `domain.com/blog`, in the most WordPress-friendly/aware way possible.

The tutorial above does provide information on how to accomplish that, but only for Apache. And I'm using Nginx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your nginx config, but the easiest way ever would be

```
location / {
  return 301 http://example.com/wordpress
}
```